# StartCoroutine() seems to not run the routine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, coroutine

I have a Sphere prefab which is just sphere with MoveSphere script attached to it. It has `Rotate()` method which starts coroutine. The Rotate() method make the sphere move along circle trajectory. The problem is when i call `Rotate()` method inside `Start()` method of MoveSphere script it works fine, but when i try to call it inside Start method of a GameController script - it doesn't work (the sphere stays at the same place). Here is my code for MoveSphere and GameController scripts:

```
public class MoveSphere : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...some fields

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        // if i uncomment next line of code - it works fine
        // Rotate();
    }

    public void Rotate()
    {
        StartCoroutine(rotate());
    }

    void Update() { }

    public IEnumerator rotate()
    {
        int n = (int)(360 / dAngle);
        float da = 360f / n;
        vAmp = radius * da * Mathf.Deg2Rad / dt;
        currentAngle = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = getPosition(currentAngle);
            currentAngle += da;
            rb.position = pos;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(dt);
        }
    }

    //...some mathematical methods
}
```

---

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;
    public int numOfInstances;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        GameObject sphere1 = Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(-5,0,-2), Quaternion.identity);

        // this one doesn't work
        sphere1.GetComponent<MoveSphere>().Rotate();
    }

    void Update () { }
}
```

Comment: Is `MoveSphere` a prefab or simply attached to an existing object in the scene?

Comment: Sphere is a prefab.

Comment: Please, explain what does "it does not work" mean. Have you any error ? Are you sure the coroutine does not start (add a simple `Debug.Log` to check) ? I am almost sure you have a `NullReferenceException` because `rb` is null. You have to call `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` inside the **Awake** method, not the **Start** one of the `MoveSphere` class.

Comment: The Rotate() method make the sphere move along circle trajectory. "It doesn't work"  means the sphere stays at the same place.

Comment: I also don't see a definition for `dt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how that happened, but i noticed that if i call it inside Update() method of caller script - it works!!!.